# Cmd start command ignores /min switch

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, windows-server-2012-r2, minimize

I'm running windows 2012 and whenever I type this in console:

```
start /min calc.exe
```

It opens the application but, it's not minimized to taskbar.

On Windonws 8.1 it actually does minimize it.

Any ideas why?

**Edit:** I want to be specific about this question as it is getting confused.

*calc.exe* above was just an example to demonstrate that /min switch is not working.

My real goal is to launch *python* and *chrome* minimized in Win 2012 R2 via command line.

Both of them do launch minimized in 8.1 when using the /min switch.

Comment: Might be a peculiarity of `calc.exe`. If you try the same with `cmd.exe`, it operates as expected.

Comment: In windows 10 it also doesn't minimize, I guess due to the fact that it is an UWP app.

Comment: That's interesting. cmd.exe is launching minimzed. However, I want to launch Python and Chrome apps minimized, and it doesn't work. Still can't understand why, because it works on Windows 8.1

Comment: Do you mean Windows Server 2012 R2?  That's the server version corresponding to Windows 8.1.

Comment: Yes, that's the one I'm running, I'm also connecting to it via RDP.

Comment: Strangely enough, minimized start does work for `notepad.exe` but not for `explorer.exe`. I guess, it is up to the application, to take the start condition seriously.

Comment: explorer.exe has always been full of bull shit

Comment: Some applications support starting with minimized window and being therefore in background and some do not. Windows Notepad is an example which supports minimized start while Windows Calculator does not support a minimized start. Firefox can be started also with minimized window using `start /min`, but only if it was last time not exited with maximized window. I suppose this is true for Chrome, too. Start Chrome, click on icon for restore window, resize the window to fill entire screen and exit it. Now start Chrome with `start /min`. Does Chrome start with minimized window in background?

Comment: As I said, everything works fine on win8.1 (this includes calculator, notepad, python and chrome... except only explorer).

Comment: Windows Calculator on Windows XP never starts minimized, but Notepad always does. It was interesting for me to read that on Windows 8.1 `calc.exe` supports starting minimized. Well, the calculator cannot be used without user interaction (in general) and therefore it really does not make sense to start it with minimized window. Other applications like text editors or browsers can be used also without user interactions which might be the reason why those applications support starting minimized. It is a matter of the application and not of `start` if starting minimized works or not.

Comment: If it was a matter of application, it would show the same behavior in win8 and windows 2012. on my windows 2012 NOTHING starts minimized.

Comment: Not sure about windows 2012, in windows 10 the `calc.exe` starts another executable (`calculator.exe`) . You can request the minimization of the first, but you have not control on how the second is launched.

Comment: Try installing the Desktop Experience feature, [found under "User Interfaces and Infrastructure"](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2012/05/01/how-to-add-desktop-experience-feature-on-windows-server-2012-server-8-beta/)  on Server 2012 R2.  That's the only relevant difference between 8.1 and 2012 R2 that I can think of.  One other random thought: does the 2012 R2 machine have a much lower screen resolution?  If Windows thinks it is running on a tablet or tablet-like machine, minimization behaviour might be affected.

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it out about the desktop experience feature. Regarding the resolution, I'm launching it 1920x1080 and my desktop is 1440p.

Comment: Is 1920x1080 the native resolution of the display (if any) attached to the server, or is it a remote connection?

Comment: A remote connection... it doesn't have a display

Comment: Try watching it in procmon to see if there's any clues

Answer (score 7):

`start /min file.exe` uses [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API call to start the process, with the adecuated information inside the [`STARTUPINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure pointed by the `lpStartupInfo` argument.

Inside this structure, there is a `wShowWindow` member to indicate how to show the window of the started process. Its documentation states

> **wShowWindow**
>
> If **dwFlags** specifies STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW, this member can be any of
>   the values that can be specified in the *nCmdShow* parameter for the
>   ShowWindow function, except for SW_SHOWDEFAULT. Otherwise, this member
>   is ignored.
>
> For GUI processes, the first time ShowWindow is called, its *nCmdShow*
>   parameter is ignored **wShowWindow** specifies the default value. In
>   subsequent calls to ShowWindow, the **wShowWindow member** is used if the
>   *nCmdShow* parameter of ShowWindow is set to SW_SHOWDEFAULT.

That is, you **depend** on how the started process handles its window management. There is nothing you could do in the `start` command to *ensure* the new window will be minimized.

**note**: `start` command uses `CreateProcess` in the case of executable files, but different arguments (a document, a URL, ...) lead to different APIs used (Ex. `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx`), but you end in the same problem after following a different path.

**note 2**: As already commented, in some cases (my case, windows 10, `calc.exe`) you start a process and it starts another one. You have not control on the second started process.

Comment: Is there any alternative cmd command I could try? Perhaps calling CreateProcess directly from command line? I would love some examples.

Comment: @Anonymous, Directly calling the CreateProcess (something that the start command already does) will have the same problem. Realize that tools as Nirsoft's [AdvancedRun](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html) also warns in its window handling *"Be aware that this option only affects programs that support it"*. Ì've tested `chrome.exe` and `python.exe` and both accept the `start /min` in windows 10, but whatever any of them do after starting is out of the control of the `start` command.

Comment: @MCND, I suspect the OPs issue is a variant of a similar problem reported on tablets, where Windows quite deliberately fails to pass the flag on to the new application.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, maybe you are right (in windows 10, in tablet mode chrome starts minimized sometimes, others not) unfortunately I'm limited to Windows 7 and 10 and can not test in the OP environment . In any case, as indicated, directly using what the OS provides all you can do is to ask the system to minimize the window on start. Even the approach in Lee Cottrell's answer (start in whatever state and then minimize) will fail for the windows 10 `calc` case. Without writting specific code for the task I don't see a clear way to deal with OP problem.

Comment: From a SO perspective I agree.  If I'm right (which I'm not at all sure of) this might be more of a Server Fault question.

Answer (score 2):

I could not do this in Command Prompt but was able to do this in PowerShell. Since you are on 2012, install the Powershell ISE from Server Manager | Manage | Add roles and features.

First I created the function from this page
[Set Window Style function](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/664020-maximize-an-open-window-with-powershell-win7)

Then I wrote these lines (Python may be named differently on your computer)

```
 (Get-Process -Name Python).MainWindowHandle | foreach { Set-WindowStyle MINIMIZE $_ }
 (Get-Process -Name Chrome).MainWindowHandle | foreach { Set-WindowStyle MINIMIZE $_ }
```

Finally, I saved this as a script and pasted it on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't wrote, that you don't want to use any tools, so here is one, that could solve your problem.
No need to install, it is from a trusted distributor (Nirsoft), so you should give it a try.
Link: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html

First you have to create a config file via gui, than you can start the probram by calling AdvancedRun.exe /run config.cfg

Hope it helps you!